# singleTask and singleInstance not respected when using PendingIntent?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, launchmode

I have an activity with launchMode set to singleTask:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.blah.blah.MyActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

I have an ongoing notification with a PendingIntent that launches that activity:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent( this,
                                    MyActivity.class );
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
stackBuilder.addParentStack( MyActivity.class );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( activityIntent );
PendingIntent resultingActivityPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent( REQUEST_CODE,
                                                                              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
...
m_notificationBuilder.setContentIntent( resultingActivityPendingIntent );
startForeground( ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID,
                 m_notificationBuilder.build() );
```

When I am interacting with an existing MyActivity, then I hit Home and restart MyActivity via the launcher, MyActivity's `onNewIntent()` gets called as expected.

The problem is that when I am interacting with an existing MyActivity, and I click on the ongoing notification, a new MyActivity is created via `onCreate()`, and the existing one is destroyed via `onDestroy()`.  I expected that MyActivity's `onNewIntent()` would be called instead.  Why doesn't this happen?

I have tried these answers without success:

- [Intent - if activity is running, bring it to front, else start a new one (from notification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039189/intent-if-activity-is-running-bring-it-to-front-else-start-a-new-one-from-n)
- [How to make notification resume and not recreate activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898047/how-to-make-notification-resume-and-not-recreate-activity)
- [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482480/flag-activity-reorder-to-front-ignored) (in this case the existing instance is not destroyed when the notification is clicked)

Comment: Why do you use TaskStackBuilder here?

Comment: I had just yanked it from Google's guide to notifications.  Turns out I should not have done that without thinking :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is due to the use of `TaskStackBuilder`. This code is causing your problem:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent( this,
                                MyActivity.class );
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create( this );
stackBuilder.addParentStack( MyActivity.class );
stackBuilder.addNextIntent( activityIntent );
PendingIntent resultingActivityPendingIntent =
         stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(REQUEST_CODE,
         PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

When you use `TaskStackBuilder` this way, it sets additional flags in the generated `Intent`s that cause the task to be reset (all Activities in the task are destroyed) before your Activity gets launched.

Instead use:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent( this,
                                MyActivity.class );
PendingIntent resultingActivityPendingIntent =
         PendingIntent.getActivity(this, REQUEST_CODE,
             activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

Comment: This solution works for me, but for some reason I had to completely uninstall my app first before it worked.  If I simply make the change, rebuild, then run (per usual), the old, incorrect behavior happens.  In fact, now that it's working correctly, if I switch back to using the TaskStackBuilder without uninstalling my app, the correct behavior still occurs!  To be sure, I can make a different change in the same class, and it will be picked up.  It's quite bizarre.  I will try to characterize it further and post a separate question, if necessary.  Thanks.

Comment: this is the best answer..spent almost 2 weeks before I found this. However as Kevin mentioned, you have to uninstall the app and then try it